# Basic python syntax error - won't print

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation

So I've installed python 3.3.4 on my machine and i'm trying to run the most basic code

```
import sys

file = "Wikipedia.org"
print str(file)
```

but I keep getting an InvalidSyntax Error.

I was wondering if there is something wrong with the install or path of python that i am running?

Comment: So now you can set question to resolved :)

Comment: @Ant - there is no such thing as resolved in SO You can mark the answer as accepted, click in the tick by the question. Don't edit the question

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I put the wrong

Comment: -1 for zero research effort.

Answer (score 3):

In python 3 you should use print()

```
file = "Wikipedia.org"
print(file)
```

And you don't need to use str() - variable file already contains string value